# typeorm update fails when updating a unique field with the save value

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

i have a service model/table/entity in typeorm, with has a field called service_name which is unique, when i try to update the table with the same value for the service_name it throws unique constraints violation error, i dont understand this, isnt the orm supposed to ignore that update,

```
@Entity('services')
class Service extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    _id!: string;

    @Column({
        nullable: false,
        unique: true
    })
    service_name!: string;

    @Column({
        nullable: true
    })
    description!: string;
    

   

    async updateService(data: any) {
            try {
                const Manager = Service.getRepository().manager;
                return Manager.transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
                    const updates = Object.keys(data);
                    // const allowedupdates = [
                    //     'service_name',
                    //     'description',
                    //     'active'
                    // ];
                    const service = await transactionalEntityManager.findOneByOrFail(Service, { _id: data._id });
                    if (!service) {
                        throw new Error("Service not found");
                    }
                    // const isvalidoperation = updates.every((update) => {
                    //     return allowedupdates.includes(update as string);
                    // });
                    // if (!isvalidoperation) {
                    //     throw new Error({ error: "Invalid updates" } as unknown as string);
                    // }
                    updates.forEach((update) => {
                        service[update] = data[update];
                    });
                    await service.save();
                    //await Service.update({ _id: service._id }, data);
                    //await Service.insert(data);
                    // await transactionalEntityManager
                    //     .createQueryBuilder()
                    //     .insert(Service)
                    //     .set(data)
                    //     .where("_id = :_id", { _id: service._id })
                    //     .execute();
                    //.update(Service, { _id: service._id }, data);
                    //TODO update subservices if any and deactivate them
                    // const subservices = await Manager.find(Subservice, { where: { service: { _id: service._id } } })
                    // subservices.forEach(async (subserv) => {
                    //     subserv.active = false;
                    //     await transactionalEntityManager.save(subserv);
                    // });
                    //await transactionalEntityManager.save(service, );
                    return service;
                })
            } catch (error) {
                return new Error(error.message);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

maybe i have this wrong, how should i go about this?

Answer (score -1):

Throwing errors in such situations is a perfectly normal convention. Just do proper error handling.